# How to count Returning users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning SQL. Now I have a table with columns: user_id, event_timestamp and event_name. I need to count new users per month (I) and users, who returned on site in the second month (II) (for example, if users' first appearances were in February and they used the site in March, they should be counted. I think I counted the first column (I), but I have no idea how to count the second one.
So as result there should be table with columns "month and year", "new user per month" and "returning_users".

```
select
    distinct date_trunc('month', u.date_timestamp) as month_and_year,
    count(*) as count_users
from (select distinct on (t.user_id) *
    from example_table.table as t
    order by t.user_id, t.date_timestamp
 ) as u
group by month_and_year
order by month_and_year
```

so, the solution from the answer works, but i still have a problem. i'm not sure, but i think that it works not really as i wanted. i tried it on a real base like that:

```
select date_trunc('month', u.ship_date) as month_and_year,
       count(distinct case when date_trunc('month', u.ship_date) = date_trunc('month', u.min_date) then cust_id end) as num_starts,
       count(distinct case when date_trunc('month', u.ship_date) = date_trunc('month', u.min_date + interval '1 month') then cust_id end) as num_returning
from (select sh.*,
             min(ship_date) over (partition by cust_id) as min_date
      from shipping.shipment as sh
     ) u

group by month_and_year
order by month_and_year
```

and i have a table like this:

```
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| month_and_year             | num_starts | num_returning |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| January 1, 2016, 12:00 AM  | 6          | 0             |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| February 1, 2016, 12:00 AM | 8          | 1             |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| March 1, 2016, 12:00 AM    | 16         | 0             |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| April 1, 2016, 12:00 AM    | 29         | 1             |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| May 1, 2016, 12:00 AM      | 23         | 9             |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| June 1, 2016, 12:00 AM     | 13         | 10            |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| July 1, 2016, 12:00 AM     | 4          | 5             |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
| August 1, 2016, 12:00 AM   | 0          | 2             |
+----------------------------+------------+---------------+
```

as you see, it looks like in july and august there are more users who returned than who just appeared. that's because this query shows who returns in **this month**, but i want to know, how many people who appeared in February, for example, returned in their **next** month (so, f.e. March). i think now this second number is in row below in *num_returning*. can you help me to do it right?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring in the first month using window functions.  Then use conditional aggregation:

```
select date_trunc('month', u.date_timestamp) as month_and_year,
       count(distinct case when date_trunc('month', u.date_timestamp) = date_trunc('month', u.dt) then user_id end) as num_starts,
       count(distinct case when date_trunc('month', u.date_timestamp) > date_trunc('month', u.dt) then user_id end) as num_returning
    count(*) as count_users
from (select t.*,
             min(u.date_timestamp) over (partition by user_id) as min_dt
      from example_table.table as t
     ) u
group by month_and_year
order by month_and_year;
```

Actually, I think it is more efficient to reduce the data to one row per user per month in the subquery:

```
select yyyymm,
       count(*) filter (where yyyymm = min_yyyymm) as num_starts,
       count(*) filter (where yyyymm > min_yyyymm) as num_returns
from (select distinct on (user_id, date_trunc('month', u.date_timestamp)),
             t.*,
             date_trunc('month', u.date_timestamp) as yyyymm,
             min(date_trunc('month', u.date_timestamp)) over (partition by user_id) as min_yyyymm
      from example_table.table as t
      order by user_id, date_trunc('month', u.dt), u.dt
     ) u
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

EDIT:

If you want the number that returned the month after they started, you can add that in too:

```
select yyyymm,
       count(*) filter (where yyyymm = min_yyyymm) as num_starts,
       count(*) filter (where yyyymm > min_yyyymm) as num_returns,
       count(*) filter (where yyyymm = min_yyyymm + interval '1 month') as num_returns_second_month
```

Comment: thank you very much! but i still have a problem, i add more information to the main post, can you help me one more time?